# Program never finishing using Tasks

Tags: c#, task

I tried to find an answer but did not find the exact same case. I would like to understand why this piece of code is not working?

```cs
    namespace Test
    {
        class Process
        {
            private bool Active = true;

            public Task Init()
            {
                Task t = new Task(() => {
                    this.Start();
                });

                t.Start();
                return t;
            }

            private void Start()
            {
                while (Active) ;
            }

            public void Stop(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
            {
                Active = false;
            }
        }

        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Process p = new Process();

                Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(p.Stop);

                Task t = p.Init();
                t.Wait();

                Console.WriteLine("The end !");
            }

        }
    }
```

Basically I have an infinite loop on a Task. 
The condition to stop the loop is to hit Ctrl-C, which call a method setting a Boolean to false.

It seems that the loop stops, but the code never ends.

Could you please explain me what am I doing wrong here and how could I make it work?

Comment: What does "it seems" mean? Did you debug and see that it really stopped?

Comment: Does the program print  "The end !" after 10 seconds if you use `t.Wait(10000);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the Cancel property of the CancelKeyPress event in True:

```
        public void Stop(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Active = false;
        }
```

You can se more info for the CancelKeyPress event in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.cancelkeypress?view=netframework-4.8